# Amazon Transcribe Job the file exceeds the maximum size of 2048.00 Mb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I try to create an **Amazon Transcribe Job** with an input file located on S3, the size of the file is 4.3 GB and when i try to create the job show me this error.

What can i do with my video?  should i convert the video, extract the audio or is there any way to do it with some AWS Service

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Amazon Transcribe FAQs – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/faqs/#:%7E:text=Amazon%20Transcribe%20supports%20both%2016,%2C%20MP3%2C%20MP4%20and%20FLAC.):

> **What kind of inputs does Amazon Transcribe support?**
>
> Amazon Transcribe supports both 16 kHz and 8kHz audio streams, and multiple audio encodings, including WAV, MP3, MP4 and FLAC.

Since Amazon Transcribe is a **service for converting spoken speech into text**, it would be best to provide it with an **audio file** rather than a video.

If you convert that 4.3 GB video into an audio file, it will probably be small enough to use with Amazon Transcribe. If you require a service to perform that conversion, you could use [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html).